# how to compile c program by asp c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am making my college project like codepad.org.

Can anyone help in that how can I compile C and C++ program with C# in ASP.NET?

I have tried this code:

```
        Process proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.Start();
        string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

but it is giving error:

```
"The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."
```

and there is no method like "UseShellExecute".

Is this the correct way of doing or is there any other method?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=UseShellExecute

Comment: thanx for the help
but i think its not working for me because "proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";" this line is opening tc nothing else

Answer (score 2):

It's all on MSDN.

[ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

So you code would just need the UseShellExecute property set to false.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: thanx for the help
but i think its not working for me because "proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";" this line is opening tc nothing else

Comment: Well of course, you will need to specify which file to compile as well. something like `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "myfile.c";` (or whatever parameters `tc.exe` takes, but that wasn't the question).

Comment: i am taking input from user, so i have to store that TextBox data in to a file, how can i do that... Thanx

Comment: StackOverflow is a site where you can get answers to specific problems after trying to solve them yourself. Saving a file is something that you almost can't fail at if you google it quickly so that is something for you to learn. If you get problems with it after trying, it should be a new question and not a comment on an answer on another question.

Answer (score 2):

use this [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether to use the operating system shell to start the process

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
```

---

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: thanx for the help
but i think its not working for me because "proc.StartInfo.FileName = "tc.exe";" this line is opening tc nothing else